# Chilkat ftp.SyncLocalDir with open files?

Tags: ftp, chilkat

I’m having an issue with ftp.SyncLocalDir when I have an open file on the local directory.

I’m using the example from http://www.example-code.com/vbnet/ftp_syncLocalTree.asp with a few minor changes. It has been working fine for a few days and then has stopped working. 
I’ve found that one of the files is open on the local directory. Looking through the http://chilkatforum.com/ forum I see that one of the answers stated that
 “Chilkat will detect errors that are likely permission/access errors and will continue with the remainder of the download.”

This is not happening for me. Looking at the last error text it states that the file is used by another process. Not other files get synchronized.
Is the something else I need to add to the code to force it to continue after the error?

Below is the last error text.

Thanks,
Steve

```
ChilkatLog:
SyncLocalDir:
DllDate: Dec  5 2014
ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.46
UnlockPrefix: *********
Username: *********
Architecture: Little Endian; 32-bit
Language: .NET 4.0
VerboseLogging: 0
commandCharset: ansi
dirListingCharset: ansi
localDirPath: Q:\TEST
mode: 2
ProgressMonitoring:
  enabled: yes
  heartbeatMs: 0
  sendBufferSize: 65536
--ProgressMonitoring
downloadDir:
  getFile2:
    localFilename: Q:\TEST/LINE_6 _13.csv
    Replacing existing local file
    openForReadWriteWin32:
      Failed to open file (2)
      localFilePath: Q:\TEST\LINE_6 _13.csv
      currentWorkingDirectory: H:\Code In Progress\LLS\Gen 3 Test And Crimp
      w-network\VB Code\trunk\FTP Syncronize\bin\Debug
      osErrorInfo: The process cannot access the file because it is being us
      ed by another process.
      localWindowsFilePath: Q:\TEST\Line 6\LINE_6 _13.csv
    --openForReadWriteWin32
  --getFile2
  Failed to download file
  failedFilename: /LINE_6 _13.csv
--downloadDir
Failed.
--SyncLocalDir
--ChilkatLog
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this new build for the .NET 4.0 Framework:

32-bit Download: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/download/preRelease/ChilkatDotNet4-9.5.0-win32.zip

64-bit Download: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/download/preRelease/ChilkatDotNet4-9.5.0-x64.zip

The feature for continuing past permission/access issues had to do with issues on the remote server as opposed to the local filesystem.  This new build should now also do the same for local permission errors.  It will be noted in the release notes for Chilkat version 9.5.0.47 when released (soon).

If you have trouble, please post the LastErrorText using this new build.